# Trying to get `sed `to fix a phpBB board - but I cannot get my regexp to work

Tags: mysql, sed, bbcode, phpbb

I have an ancient phpBB3 board which has gone through several updates over its 15+ years of existence. Sometimes, in the distant past, such updates would partially fail, leaving all sorts of 'garbage' in the BBCode. I'm now trying to do a 'simple' regexp to match a particular issue and fix it.

What happened was the following... during a database update, long long ago, BBCode tags were, for some reason, 'tagged' with a pseudo-attribute — allegedly for the database updating script to figure out each token that required updating, I guess. This attribute was always a 8-char-long alphanumeric string, 'appended' to the actual BBCode with a semicolon, like this:

```
[I]something in italic[/I]
...
[I:i9o7y3ew]something in italic[/I:i9o7y3ew]
```

Naturally, phpBB doesn't recognise this as valid BBCode, and just prints the whole text out.

The replacement regexp is actually very basic:

```
s/\[(\/?)(.+):[[:alnum:]]{0,8}\]/[\1\2]/gim
```

You can see a working example on [regex110.com](https://regex101.com/r/ngAwlv/1) (where capture groups use `$1` instead of `\1`). The example given there includes a few examples from the actual database itself. `[i]` is actually the simplest case; there are plenty of others which are perfectly valid but a bit more complex, thus requiring a `(.+)` matcher, such as `[quote=\"Gwyneth Llewelyn\":2m80kuso]`.

As you can see from the example on regex110.com, this works :-)

Why doesn't it work under (GNU) `sed`? I'm using version 4.8 under Linux:

```bash
$ sed -i.bak -E "s/\[(\/?)(.+):[[:alnum:]]+\]/[\1\2]/gim" table.sql
```

Just for the sake of the argument, I *tried* using `[A-Za-z0-9]+` instead of `[[:alnum:]]+`; I've even tried `(.+)` (to capture the group and then just discard it)

None produced an error; none did any replacements whatsoever.

I understand that there are many different regexp engines out there (PCRE, PCRE2, Boost, etc. and so forth) so perhaps `sed` is using a syntax that is inconsistent with what I'm expecting...?

Rationale: well, I could have done this differently; after all, MySQL has built-in regexp replacements, too. However, since this particular table is so big, it takes eternities. I thought I'd be far better off by dumping everything to a text file, doing the replacements there, and importing the table again. There is a catch, though: the file is 95 MBytes in size, which means that *most* tools I've got (e.g. editors with built-in regexp search & replace) will fail with such a huge exception. One notable exception is good old `emacs`, which has no trouble with such large files. Alas, `emacs` cannot match anything, so I thought I'd give `sed` a try (it should be faster, too). `sed` takes also close to a minute or so to process the whole file — about the same as `emacs`, in fact — and has the same result, i.e. no replacements are being made. It seems to me that, although the underlying technology is so different (pure C vs. Emacs-LISP), both these tools somehow rely on similar algorithms... both of which fail.

My understanding is that *some* libraries use different conventions to signal literal vs. metacharacters and quantifiers. Here is an example from an instruction manual for `vim`: http://www.vimregex.com/#compare

Indeed, contemporary versions of `sed` *seem* to be able to handle two different kinds of conventions (thus the `-E` flag). The issue I have with *my* regexp is that I find it very difficult to figure out which convention to apply. Let's start with what I'm used to from PHP, Go, JavaScript and a plethora of other regexp implementations, which use the convention that *metacharacters & quantifiers do not get backslashed* (while literals do).

Thus, `\[(\/?)(.+):[[:alnum:]]+\]` presumes that there are a few literal matches for `[`, `]`, `/`, and only these few cases require backslashes.

Using the reverse convention — i.e. literals do *not* get backslashed, while metacharacters and *some* quantifies do — this would be written as:

```
[\(/\?\)\(\.\+\):\[\[:alnum:\]\]\+]
```

Or so I would think.

Sadly, `sed` also rejects this with an error — and so do `vim` and `emacs`, BTW (they seem to use a similar regexp library, or perhaps even the same one).

So what is the correct way to write my regexp so that `sed` accepts it (and does what I intend it to do)?

---

### UPDATE

I have since learned that, *in the database*, phpBB, unlike I assumed, does *not* store BBCode (!) but rather a variant of HTML (some tags are the same, some are invented on the spot). What happens is that BBCode gets translated into that pseudo-HTML, and back again when displaying; that, at least, explains why phpBB extensions such as [Markdown for phpBB](https://github.com/AlfredoRamos/phpbb-ext-markdown) — but also BBCode add-ons! — can so easily replace, partially or even totally, whatever is in the database, which will continue to work (to a degree!) even if those extensions get deactivated: the parsed BBCode/Markdown is just converted to this 'special' styling *in the database*, and, as such, will *always* be rendered correctly by phpBB3, no matter what.

On other words, fixing those 'broken' phpBB tags requires a bit more processing, and not merely search & replace with a single regexp.

Nevertheless, my question is still pertinent to me. I'm not really an expert with regexps but I know the basics — enough to make my life so much easier! — and it's always good to understand the different 'dialects' used by different platforms.

Notably, instead of using `egrep` and/or `grep -E`, I'm fond of using [`ugrep`](https://github.com/Genivia/ugrep)  instead. It uses PCRE2 expressions (with the [Boost](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_79_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html) library), and maybe that's the issue I'm having with the `sed` engine(s) — the different engines speak different regular expressions dialect, and converting from one grep variant to a different one might *not* be useful at all (because some options will not 'translate' well enough)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sed`

- `(\[[^:]*)` - Retain everything up to but not including the next semi colon after a opening bracket within the parenthesis which can later be returned with back reference `\1`
- `[^]]*` - Exclude everything else up to but not including the next closing bracket

```
$ sed -E 's/(\[[^:]*)[^]]*/\1/g' table.sql
[I]something in italic[/I]
...
[I]something in italic[/I]
```

Comment: Well done, I haven't even thanked you properly! I admit I'm really bad at thinking about _negative_ matches in regexp and keep forgetting that these are not only possible, but rather neatly solve the most thorny issues... your answer is really much appreciated!

Comment: @GwynethLlewelyn You're welcome. It is my pleasure to help. Accepting the answer (or upvote) is more than enough thanks.